# JavaScript API: listener to the editing of the cell content

Tags: ms-office, office-js

When a user double-clicks an Excel cell, they can edit its content; they can also edit the selected cell in the formula bar. I am wondering if JavaScript API has a listener to the editing of the content, which includes all the details: adding a character, removing a character, moving the focus in the cell...

It seems that [bindingselectionchangeevent](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.bindingselectionchangedevent) is not for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, "as-you-type" APIs are not available in Excel. You must wait until the developer enters information in one or more cells to read that information.